# How to use LASTKEY in OpenEdge

Tags: openedge

I've just spent pretty well a whole day trying to understand why this (simplified version) didn't work;

```
DO WHILE NOT lUserQuit:
   DO ON ENDKEY UNDO, LEAVE:
      iIssueNumber = ?.
      UPDATE iIssueNumber
             GO-ON(RETURN F4 F6)
             WITH FRAME iIssueNumber-f
                  ROW 10
                  COLUMN 5
                  NO-LABELS.
      END.

   RUN WrtToLogfile("{&FILE-NAME}: {&LINE-NUMBER}: " +
                    "Issue number from keyboard: " +
                       STRING(iIssueNumber)) +
                    " KEYFUNCTION(LASTKEY):" +
                        cFunctionLastKey).

   IF KEYFUNCTION(LASTKEY) = "END-ERROR" THEN DO:
      lUserQuit = TRUE.
      iIssueNumber = ?.
      END.
   ELSE IF KEYFUNCTION(LASTKEY) = "F6" THEN DO:
      ....
      END.
   END.
```

(WrtToLogfile is a function which adds the value of its character expression argument to a logfile... not included for brevity!)

This code seems to be acting as if the call to WrtToLogfile gobbles up the value left by the UPDATE and from then on the code just never gets to see it after that?

PS I'm quite sure that this could all be done much better with an event driven program but the code I'm supporting is *very* old :-) (and so am I).

(I have the "ABL Reference" PDF page for the LASTKEY function open on my desktop and it doesn't warn you of this!)

Best wishes to everyone...

Allan

Answer (score 3):

This code might help to better illustrate what is going on. If you run the code below you will see that LASTKEY can be safely checked many times and will continue to show the expected value.

```
define variable something as character no-undo.
define variable nothing   as character no-undo.
define variable allDone   as logical   no-undo.
define variable step      as character no-undo.
define variable kvalue    as integer   no-undo format "->>>9".
define variable kf        as character no-undo format "x(20)".
define variable kl        as character no-undo format "x(20)".

form
  step kvalue kf kl skip
 with
  frame b
  down
  no-box
.

do while allDone = no:

  allDone = no.

  do on endkey undo, leave:

    update
      something go-on( return f4 f6 )
     with
      frame a
    .

    display "1" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
    down with frame b.

    run logsomething.

    display "2" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
    down with frame b.

    if keyfunction( lastkey ) = "end-error" then do:

      display "3" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
      down with frame b.

      allDone = yes.
      something = ?.

    end.
    else if keyfunction( lastkey ) = "f6" then do:

      display "4" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
      down with frame b.

    end.

  end.

  display "5" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
  down with frame b.

end.

procedure logsomething:

  display "1a" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
  down with frame b.

  output to value( "something.log" ).
  put lastkey skip.
  output close.

  display "1b" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
  down with frame b.

  input from value( "something.log" ).
  import nothing.
  input close.

  display "1c" @ step lastkey @ kvalue keyfunction( lastkey) @ kf keylabel( lastkey) @ kl with frame b.
  down with frame b.

  return.

end.
```

In the output below I typed "abc" followed bt RETURN, then "def" followed by F6 and then, finally F4:

```
step     kvalue kf                   kl
──────── ────── ──────────────────── ────────────────────
1            13 RETURN               RETURN
1a           13 RETURN               RETURN
1b           13 RETURN               RETURN
1c           13 RETURN               RETURN
2            13 RETURN               RETURN
5            13 RETURN               RETURN
1           306 PUT                  F6
1a          306 PUT                  F6
1b          306 PUT                  F6
1c          306 PUT                  F6
2           306 PUT                  F6
5           306 PUT                  F6
5           404 END-ERROR            PF4
```

What you are seeing is that, for F6, the KEY**FUNCTION** is "PUT" not, "F6". So your logic checking for F6 is always going to miss it. The KEY**LABEL** is "F6".

Additionally the F4 key is treated as END-ERROR and handled by the "DO ON ENDKEY..." rather than the GO-ON. So that block of logic also gets skipped.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm humbled once again.  I really thought I had found an OpenEdge glitch for  a while :-)  (The "KEYFUNCTION" error you spotted was introduced when I hand-copied from the original faulty code onto this entry...should check my editing more carefully!)

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the rewrite.... sorry saw the instruction about house style after writing query... Apologies.